# Solr does not search into integers?

Tags: search, configuration, solr, integer

I'm currently developping a search engine using Solr for an ecommerce website. So I get these two fields in my schema.xml:

```
   <field name="sku" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
   <field name="collection" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
```

(The complete schema.xml is available below)

For information:

- sku looks like this: 959620, 929345, 912365, ...
- collection looks like this: Alcott, Spigrim, Tantal,...

They are well indexed. For instance, when I look for:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/myindex/select/?q=Alcott
```

I got all products with collection "Alcott".

But when I look for;

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/myindex/select/?q=959620
```

I got nothing.

However, when I go deep forward with this request,

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/myindex/select/?q=sku:969520
```

I do have the product attached to this sku.

Is there any way to have "q=969520" working ? And even better: "q=96" resulting all products with sku starting by "96" ?

Thank you for your help !

schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<schema name="example" version="1.2">


  <types>

    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

    <!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!--Binary data type. The data should be sent/retrieved in as Base64 encoded Strings -->
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>


    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>


    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>


    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <!-- A Trie based date field for faster date range queries and date faceting. -->
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>



    <fieldType name="pint" class="solr.IntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="plong" class="solr.LongField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="pfloat" class="solr.FloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="pdouble" class="solr.DoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="pdate" class="solr.DateField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>



    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="slong" class="solr.SortableLongField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sfloat" class="solr.SortableFloatField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sdouble" class="solr.SortableDoubleField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>


    <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" indexed="true" />


    <!-- A text field that only splits on whitespace for exact matching of words -->
    <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
        <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
          add enablePositionIncrements=true in both the index and query
          analyzers to leave a 'gap' for more accurate phrase queries.
        -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_fr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

      <analyzer type="query">
        <!-- normalisation des accents, cédilles, e dans l'o,... -->
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <!-- découpage selon les espaces -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- suppression de la ponctuation -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(\p{Punct}*)(.*?)(\p{Punct}*)$" replacement="$2"/>
        <!-- suppression des tokens vides et des mots démesurés -->
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />
        <!-- passage en minuscules -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- suppression des élisions (l', qu',...) -->
        <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="elisionwords_fr.txt"/> 
        <!-- découpage des mots composés -->
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" stemEnglishPossessive="1" generateWordParts="1"
                                                        generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <!-- suppression des mots insignifiants -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="1" words="stopwords_fr.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <!-- gestion des synonymes -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_fr.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <!-- partie de mot -->
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="6"/>
        <!-- lemmatisation (pluriels,...) -->
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French" protected="protwords_fr.txt"/>
        <!-- suppression des doublons éventuels -->
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>



      <analyzer type="index">
        <!-- normalisation des accents, cédilles, e dans l'o,... -->
        <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt"/>
        <!-- découpage selon les espaces -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- suppression de la ponctuation -->
        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="^(\p{Punct}*)(.*?)(\p{Punct}*)$" replacement="$2"/>
        <!-- suppression des tokens vides et des mots démesurés -->
        <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />
        <!-- passage en minuscules -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <!-- suppression des élisions (l', qu',...) -->
        <filter class="solr.ElisionFilterFactory" articles="elisionwords_fr.txt"/> 
        <!-- découpage des mots composés -->
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" stemEnglishPossessive="1" generateWordParts="1"
                                                        generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <!-- suppression des mots insignifiants -->
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="1" words="stopwords_fr.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
        <!-- gestion des synonymes -->
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_fr.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <!-- partie de mot -->
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="6"/>
        <!-- lemmatisation (pluriels,...) -->
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="French" protected="protwords_fr.txt"/>
        <!-- suppression des doublons éventuels -->
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>




    <!-- Less flexible matching, but less false matches.  Probably not ideal for product names,
         but may be good for SKUs.  Can insert dashes in the wrong place and still match. -->
    <fieldType name="textTight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="0" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <!-- this filter can remove any duplicate tokens that appear at the same position - sometimes
             possible with WordDelimiterFilter in conjuncton with stemming. -->
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <!-- A general unstemmed text field - good if one does not know the language of the field -->
    <fieldType name="textgen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <!-- A general unstemmed text field that indexes tokens normally and also
         reversed (via ReversedWildcardFilterFactory), to enable more efficient 
   leading wildcard queries. -->
    <fieldType name="text_rev" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ReversedWildcardFilterFactory" withOriginal="true"
           maxPosAsterisk="3" maxPosQuestion="2" maxFractionAsterisk="0.33"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true"
                words="stopwords.txt"
                enablePositionIncrements="true"
                />
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <fieldType name="alphaOnlySort" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <!-- KeywordTokenizer does no actual tokenizing, so the entire
             input string is preserved as a single token
          -->
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!-- The LowerCase TokenFilter does what you expect, which can be
             when you want your sorting to be case insensitive
          -->
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <!-- The TrimFilter removes any leading or trailing whitespace -->
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />

        <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
                pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all"
        />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldtype name="phonetic" stored="false" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.DoubleMetaphoneFilterFactory" inject="false"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>

    <fieldtype name="payloads" stored="false" indexed="true" class="solr.TextField" >
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <!--
        The DelimitedPayloadTokenFilter can put payloads on tokens... for example,
        a token of "foo|1.4"  would be indexed as "foo" with a payload of 1.4f
        Attributes of the DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory : 
         "delimiter" - a one character delimiter. Default is | (pipe)
   "encoder" - how to encode the following value into a playload
      float -> org.apache.lucene.analysis.payloads.FloatEncoder,
      integer -> o.a.l.a.p.IntegerEncoder
      identity -> o.a.l.a.p.IdentityEncoder
            Fully Qualified class name implementing PayloadEncoder, Encoder must have a no arg constructor.
         -->
        <filter class="solr.DelimitedPayloadTokenFilterFactory" encoder="float"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>

    <!-- lowercases the entire field value, keeping it as a single token.  -->
    <fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <!-- since fields of this type are by default not stored or indexed,
         any data added to them will be ignored outright.  --> 
    <fieldtype name="ignored" stored="false" indexed="false" multiValued="true" class="solr.StrField" /> 

 </types>


 <fields>
 <!-- Vu fields -->
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
   <field name="sku" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" /> 
   <field name="collection" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" /> 
   <field name="title" type="text_fr" required="false" />
   <field name="description" type="text_fr" required="false" />
   <field name="price" type="float" required="false" indexed="true" stored="false" />
   <field name="brand_id" type="text" required="false" />
   <field name="date_online" type="date" required="false" />
   <field name="product_type" type="text" required="false" />   
   <field name="selection_id" type="sint" required="false" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false" />
   <field name="stock_delay" type="sint" required="false"  />
   <field name="stock" type="sint" required="false"  />
   <field name="price_type" type="sint" required="false"  />
   <field name="main_product_id" type="text" required="false"  />
   <field name="date_price" type="date" required="false" />
   <!-- attributes -->
   <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="sint" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <field name="attr_13" type="int" indexed="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="attr_14" type="int" indexed="true" multiValued="false"/>
   <field name="attr_19" type="int" indexed="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <!-- Ce champ contiendra la copie de tous les autres, pour faciliter la recherche -->
   <field name="global" type="text_fr" required="false" multiValued="true" />


   <!-- Valid attributes for fields:
     name: mandatory - the name for the field
     type: mandatory - the name of a previously defined type from the 
       <types> section
     indexed: true if this field should be indexed (searchable or sortable)
     stored: true if this field should be retrievable
     compressed: [false] if this field should be stored using gzip compression
       (this will only apply if the field type is compressable; among
       the standard field types, only TextField and StrField are)
     multiValued: true if this field may contain multiple values per document
     omitNorms: (expert) set to true to omit the norms associated with
       this field (this disables length normalization and index-time
       boosting for the field, and saves some memory).  Only full-text
       fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.
     termVectors: [false] set to true to store the term vector for a
       given field.
       When using MoreLikeThis, fields used for similarity should be
       stored for best performance.
     termPositions: Store position information with the term vector.  
       This will increase storage costs.
     termOffsets: Store offset information with the term vector. This 
       will increase storage costs.
     default: a value that should be used if no value is specified
       when adding a document.
   -->
    <!--
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
   <field name="sku" type="textTight" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <field name="name" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="alphaNameSort" type="alphaOnlySort" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="manu" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true"/>
   <field name="cat" type="text_ws" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" />
   <field name="features" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="includes" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />

   <field name="weight" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="price"  type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="popularity" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="inStock" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    -->

   <!-- Common metadata fields, named specifically to match up with
     SolrCell metadata when parsing rich documents such as Word, PDF.
     Some fields are multiValued only because Tika currently may return
     multiple values for them.
   -->
   <!--
   <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="subject" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="comments" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="author" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="keywords" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="category" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="content_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="last_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="links" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    -->

   <!-- catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
        via copyField further on in this schema  -->
   <!-- <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/> -->

   <!-- catchall text field that indexes tokens both normally and in reverse for efficient
        leading wildcard queries. -->
   <!-- <field name="text_rev" type="text_rev" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/> -->

   <!-- non-tokenized version of manufacturer to make it easier to sort or group
        results by manufacturer.  copied from "manu" via copyField -->
   <!-- <field name="manu_exact" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/> -->

   <!-- <field name="payloads" type="payloads" indexed="true" stored="true"/> -->

   <!-- Uncommenting the following will create a "timestamp" field using
        a default value of "NOW" to indicate when each document was indexed.
     -->
   <!--
   <field name="timestamp" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
     -->


   <!-- Dynamic field definitions.  If a field name is not found, dynamicFields
        will be used if the name matches any of the patterns.
        RESTRICTION: the glob-like pattern in the name attribute must have
        a "*" only at the start or the end.
        EXAMPLE:  name="*_i" will match any field ending in _i (like myid_i, z_i)
        Longer patterns will be matched first.  if equal size patterns
        both match, the first appearing in the schema will be used.  -->
   <!--
   <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
    -->

   <!-- some trie-coded dynamic fields for faster range queries -->
   <!--
   <dynamicField name="*_ti" type="tint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tl" type="tlong"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tf" type="tfloat"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_td" type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*_tdt" type="tdate"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="*_pi"  type="pint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" multiValued="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="attr_*" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

   <dynamicField name="random_*" type="random" />
    -->
   <!-- uncomment the following to ignore any fields that don't already match an existing 
        field name or dynamic field, rather than reporting them as an error. 
        alternately, change the type="ignored" to some other type e.g. "text" if you want 
        unknown fields indexed and/or stored by default --> 
   <!--dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" /-->

 </fields>

 <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. 
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
   -->
 <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

 <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
 <defaultSearchField>global</defaultSearchField>

 <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
 <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>

  <!-- copyField commands copy one field to another at the time a document
        is added to the index.  It's used either to index the same field differently,
        or to add multiple fields to the same field for easier/faster searching.  -->

   <copyField source="title" dest="global"/>
   <copyField source="description" dest="global"/>


</schema>
```

Comment: Can you post your `schema.xml` by any chance?

Comment: There are a few settings that can affect that behavior in `schema.xml`. You're better off posting the whole thing.

Comment: done ! (god, this file is huge...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes add a directive like this in your schema.xml after the field definitions:

```
<copyField source="sku" dest="text">
```

assuming that the defaultSearchField is set to `text`.

To search for all SKUs beginning with 96 you can search for 96*. Keep in mind though this will return all fields (not just SKUs) that begin with 96. To restrict it to SKUs, you will have to search for `sku:96*`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the behavior described it sounds like you're trying to use basic SearchHandler query syntax out of the box to search against multiple fields. That's not going to work out as you'd hope.

There are numerous options available:

1. Front-end the query so that fully-qualified field names get sent (eg "fielda:foo OR fieldb:foo")
2. Copy the contents of searchable fields into a single search field (through copyField) and make that the default field to search
3. Use Solr Dismax syntax and specify multiple QueryFields (qf parameter in the request)

Since you have fields of different types, and want to apply wildcard matching and other such things, I'd recommend you go the Dismax route and look into creating a Query Handler that better suits your needs:

More info on:

- The default SearchHandler: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler
- Solr with Dismax: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a `copyField` setting for the fields you want to be searchable by default.

Since your `defaultSearchField` is set to `global`, try:

```
<copyField source="sku" dest="global"/>
```

You'll probably want to do the same for `collection`:

```
<copyField source="collection" dest="global"/>
```

In order to have partial matches (e.g.: ?q=95) without special operators, you need to tweak the NGram filter. Your current setting, for both the index-time and the query-time analyzer is:

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="6"/>
```

This means that partial matching will be available from 3 to 6 characters, per example:

- 959
- 9596
- 95962
- 596
- ...

If you want to allow it from 2 characters (e.g.: `95`), change the `minGramSize` in both analyzers' filters and you should be good to go:

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="6"/>
```

Lastly, your `global` field probably shouldn't be stored (by default) but only indexed:

```
<field name="global" type="text_fr" indexed="true" stored="false" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

Remember that you need to restart Solr and re-index for the changes to be in effect.