# Solr Wildcard search on int field

Tags: solr

My schema.xml for Solr has many integer fields.

How do I do wildcard searching for int fields? I have many dyanamic fields for int values as shown below.

```
<dynamicField name="*_nbr" type="int" stored="true"/>
```

eg:
I have a field called `store_nbr` and I want to find all stores that start with 280.
I tried giving `store_nbr:280*`, but it didn't return any results. Similarly I have many such integer fields.

Answer (score 3):

While the answer from @Kumar hints in the correct direction (but don't use a text field from the default schema.xml for this, as it will process any input both when querying and indexing), the explanation is that you might need a new field to do wild card queries against, unless you can transform your query into an actual integer operation (if all your store_nbr-s are of the same length).

Add a StrField (in the default schema.xml, there is a defined type named "string" that is a simple string field that suites this purpose):

```
<field name="store_nbr_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

Add a copyField directive that copies the value from the `store_nbr` field into the string field when indexing:

```
<copyField source="store_nbr" dest="store_nbr_text" />
```

Then query against this field for prefix matches, using the syntax you already described (`store_nbr:280*`).

If this particular query format (querying for the three first digits of a store_nbr) is very common, you'll want to transform the content on the way in to index the three first digits in a dedicated field, as it'll give you better query performance and a smaller cache.

And if you're doing a lot of wild card queries (with varying lengths in front of *), look into have a field generate EdgeNGrams instead, as these will give you dedicated tokens that solr looks up instead of having a wild card search which may have to traverse a larger set of possible tokens to determine whether the document should be returned.

Comment: You are missing a tag close for `copyField`: `<copyField source="store_nbr" dest="store_nbr_text"/>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I already tried that. However what I found is once I give the copy field directive, and I do a search, it works for the new rows inserted. It doesn't work for the old rows. Is there a way we can search previously inserted rows as well.

Comment: No, adding a new field require you to reindex the content to get the field populated. Unless all your integers are within the same length (so you can do an interval search on integers instead), you'll have to reindex to be able to do string based prefix matches.

Comment: I am new to Solr. Could you let me know to reindex a field

Comment: Also in the given solution for me it didn't work with store_nbr:280* for the inserted new row, but it worked with the new field store_nbr_text with the query store_nbr_text:280*

Answer (score 0):

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11057309/3496666) answer. You have to add a directive link in your schema.xml in {solr_home}/example/solr/**your_collection**/conf/schema.xml as shown in that answer. Copy all your fields to make it searchable for wildcard query.